# How to change the db name dynamically using one db  storedprocedures to another db storedprocedures?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, asp.net-4.0

I am using one database like **Test(db name)** in this database i added 10 tables and 5 **stored procedures** , now i can call that procedures in another database like **Test2(db name)** ,
i am writing like this

```
Test database stored procedure is 

Create proc GetDetails()
As
select * from Emp;
```

after that storedprocedure using in another database like

```
    Test2  database stored procedure is 

    Create proc GetDetails()
    As
Begin
    Exec Test..GetDetails()
End
```

Now client **import the databases change the names as client wish** now all stored procedures are not working in this situation how to solve the problem pls give me any suggestion , i can dynamically change the database name in all stored procedure.

Thanking u
Hemanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can pass the target database name to the Test2 sproc (or read it from a configuration table or something), then you could use it like this:

```
-- assume @dbname has the name of the database where getdetails was created
declare @sql nvarchar(4000), @params nvarchar(4000), @dbname sysname
set @dbname = 'test'
set @sql = @dbname + '..getdetails'
set @params = ''
exec sp_executesql @sql, @params
```